# Split IEC 61131-3 DINT into two INT variables (PLC structured text)

Tags: matlab, modbus, plc, st

I want to publish a DINT variable (dintTest) over MODBUS on a PLC to read it with Matlab Instrument Control Toolbox. Turns out, Matlab can read Modbus variables but only INT16. So i want to split the DINT variable into two INT variables in IEC. I found this solution, but this only allows values from +- 0 ... 32767^2:

```
dintTest := -2;

b := dintTest MOD 32767;
a := dintTest / 32767;
result := 32767 * a + b;

c := DINT_TO_INT(b); // publish over modbus
d := DINT_TO_INT(a); // publish over modbus
```

What would be the solution for the whole range of DINT?
Thanks!

edit:
I read with a matlab function block in simulink (requires Instrument Control Toolbox):

```
function Check = MBWriteHoldingRegs(Values,RegAddr)
coder.extrinsic('modbus');
m = modbus('tcpip', '192.169.237.17');
coder.extrinsic('write');
write(m,'holdingregs',RegAddr,double(Values),'int16');
Check = Values;
```

Comment: By quickly looking, Matlab supports 32 bit variables for modbus. Please check [this link](https://se.mathworks.com/help/instrument/read-data-from-a-modbus-server.html) under "Specifying Server ID and Precision". So basically you just read the DINT from PLC by giving the starting address of the variable and then read it using `read(m,'holdingregs',1,2,'uint32');` or similar. If you need to divide the DINT to two INTs, it is possible with MEMCPY for example. Please provide more information if you need help.

Comment: Thanks, yes, Matlab supports 32 bit variables, but (i guess) with another representation. When reading a variable, the only combination of variables that gives the same result is Matlab 'int16' and IEC 'INT'.

Comment: Could you provide some example how you are actually doing the reading? I haven't used the matlab modbus myself, just normal modbus.

Comment: Yes, I added the matlab function code to the original question.

Comment: Could you try to use DINT at PLC and then write to it with `write(m,'holdingregs',RegAddr,Values,'int32');` or something similar?

Comment: That is what i tried, many combinations of matlab and IEC datatypes. The only combination that works is INT and int16.

Answer (score 0):

I would better split DINT to 2 WORD

```
VAR
    diInt: DINT := -2;
    dwTemp: DWORD;
    w1: WORD;
    w2: WORD;
END_VAR


dwTemp := DINT_TO_DWORD(diInt);

w1 := DWORD_TO_WORD(dwTemp);
w2 := DWORD_TO_WORD(SHR(dwTemp, 16));
```

And then I could build it back in matlab.

The point here is not using mathematic but bit masks.